# Infinite limit square root problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives, contest-math

How can I define
                $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}}$$

Comment: This is not legible. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for formatting tips.

Comment: Please try to typeset this with MathJax and $\LaTeX$ to make it readable.  It is not clear if you are trying to find $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}}$ or something else

Answer (score 1):

We have that:
$$ \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}} = \sqrt{\frac{x}{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}}}} \to 1$$
As $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Should be 1/x^(3/2) instead of 1/x^(1/2)

Comment: good catch, careless error, thank you @SteezO-

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=m^2$ then

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}}=\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\frac{m}{
\sqrt{m^2+m\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{m}}}}=\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\frac{1}{
\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{m}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{m}}}}\to 1$$